# Parcellite menu appears at startup

Tags: 14.04, clipboard, clipboard-manager

The menu appears when Parcellite is started. This happens at boot-up and if I start it using the Dash button. See animated GIF below. I've removed and re-installed Parcellite. I've also deleted **~/.config/parcellite** directory. No luck. How can I prevent the Parcellite menu from appearing at start-up?

Ubuntu 14.04
Parcellite 1.1.7

[image: Parcellite menu appears at startup - animated GIF]

Comment: Seems like a bug. I use Parcellite 1.0.2rc5 with XFCE in Debian 7 and that does not happen.

Comment: Not a solution but you can try Diodon, a simple clipboar manager for Gnome.

Comment: Trying out Diodon. Thanks xangua. The history hot-key seems to be a little hesitant. I have to hold the keys down for a second before the history list appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is Unity? :) bug report here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/parcellite/bugs/118

And it is fixed in SVN.

And BTW, thanks for the great vid - makes the developer's life easier.

Comment: The fix hit my Ubuntu 14.04 system 06/28/2014. Thanks.